# Use Excel conditional formatting based on cell display, not content of cell formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

In my Excel worksheet, I have a cell containing the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNT(Y11:AA11)>0,SUM(Y11:AA11),#N/A)
```

with the goal of a chart later using the display of the cell in a graph (excluding the display of any 0 values), which it does.

The issue I have is that there are a lot of `#N/A` display values that look messy, so I want to use conditional formatting to make the cases when `#N/A` is displayed have white text. So far every attempt makes every value have white text regardless of if the display value is `#N/A` or a number. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Things I have tried:

- Using conditional formatting with formula condition of `=ISERROR($X$4:$X$37)`,
  applied to the range `$X$4:$X$37`. 
  (All cells in the range are formatted to use white text;
  valid numbers and error values.)
- Using conditional formatting with formula condition of `=ISNA($X$4:$X$37)`
  (same result).
- Using conditional formatting with affectation only to duplicates
  (Displaying number still affected)
- Changing formula in the cells (`X4:X37`)
  to `=IF(COUNT(Y11:AA11)>0,SUM(Y11:AA11),"#N/A")`,
  then conditional formatting that text.
  (Zero value now displays on graph since `"#N/A"` is text and `#N/A` was not.)

Here’s an image of what I’ve tried:
[image: Conditional Formatting Rules Manager]

Comment: Try putting `#N/A` in quotes in your formula: `=IF(COUNT(Y11:AA11)>0,SUM(Y11:AA11),"#N/A")`

Comment: When I use "#N/A" Excel interprets this as text and displays a 0 value in my chart instead of no value.

Comment: @Scott updated entry to reflect your suggection

Comment: Thanks for updating your question.   I have embedded the image for you.   (As you have discovered, you must have 10 reputation points to show an image; that’s to deter spam.   It’s routine for us users who have ≥ 10 rep to review images and embed them if they aren’t spam.)   But (1) Máté Juhász said that the answer is to use a formula like `=ISERROR(A2)` to determine which cells to format.   In your example, you should use `=ISERROR(X4)`.   The point is that the argument to any of the `ISxxx()` functions should be a single value, not a range.   (I can’t even figure out   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  what it’s doing when you call them with a range, but that’s a mystery puzzle I’ll leave for another day.)  (In your defense, I’ll point out that, while the `ISERROR` documentation repeatedly says that you pass it ***A*** value, I don’t see where it ever says that the parameter must not be a range or an array.)  So try that; the Conditional Formatting mechanism takes care of handling each cell from `X4` to `X37`.  And don’t use **`$`** signs.  If you say `=ISERROR($X$4)`, then the entire range will turn white if `X4` is an error (and vice versa).   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Here’s a trick for doing conditional formatting: put a formula in cell `AC4` (or `AX4`, or anywhere that’s convenient and not in use) that will evaluate to TRUE if you want `X4` to be formatted and FALSE if you don’t.  Obviously, that formula would be `=ISERROR(X4)`.  Make sure it works if you drag/fill it down to `AC37`.  (Since that formula *doesn’t* include `$` signs, `AC37` will be filled in with `=ISERROR(X37)`, which is what you want.)  Once you get that working, there’s about a 95% chance that the formula in `AC4` will work  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  for the conditional formatting of `$X$4:$X$37`.  Another way of looking at it is that the “formula to determine which cells to format” should refer to the upper-left cell in the “Applies to” range.  (Obviously, if you want `X17` to change color if ``SUM(A17:W17)`` is greater than 42, then you need to use a range parameter to `SUM()`.)  (3) It’s a little disappointing, that, (3a) even after Máté posted his answer showing ``=ISERROR(A2)``, you (apparently) didn’t try that, and (3b) even after Máté asked about “Stop If True”, you uploaded a screenshot that has that column cropped off.

Comment: when you enter the formula, it should refer to one cell only (the active one in the selection), not the whole range `=ISNA(X4)`, and you need to use relative references, not absolute (not `$X$4`)

Answer (score 1):

- Select your data you want to format
- go to home - conditional formatting - new rule
- select "use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- enter formula:
  `=ISERROR(A2)`
  *(replace `A2` to address of active cell)*
- select the format you need (in the example below I've used yellow highlight to make my answer clear)

[image]

Comment: When doing this my numbers displaying are still affected as well.

Comment: do you have other conditional formatting rules too? Can you post a screenshot of your data?

Comment: I'm not sure how to post a screenshot, but the only other conditional formatting rule is to highlight a day that occurs on a weekend in yellow, and the formatting I am struggling with makes font white.

Comment: Isn't "stop if true" checked? (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-conditional-formatting-rule-precedence-e09711a3-48df-4bcb-b82c-9d8b8b22463d)

Comment: For the formatting intending to whitefont the #N/A? No, when this is checked the entire cell goes white with or without the display of the cell being a #N/A or number.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help without a screenshot. Please upload it to somewhere (e.g. imgur), than post the link in your question, somebody with enough reputation will edit it for you.

Comment: I tried that and got an error message saying I need 10 reputation points to show an image, but I added a link up there and in this comment the upload to imgur is this [link](https://imgur.com/BAY2A8l)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the absolute references in your `ISNA()` function.

`ISNA()` is **ONLY** returning the result for the first cell in the range used. So if it activates the CF-ing, it will do so for all the cells the rule is applied to because no matter the cell applied to, it will never look to anything other than the first cell in that absolute range.

`ISNA()` will never look at the other cells in the range even if you let them be relative references.

**BUT** it works if you at least let the row reference be relative. That is because the range examined by `ISNA()` keeps changing so the first cell is the cell you actually want looked at. That happens on each new row so while it looks the same, pretty much, you are actually changing the first cell in the range, without seeing it happen visibly, and so `ISNA()` is looking to a new first cell each time.

If you make the change and look at the CF rule with the cell highlight in different rows each time, you will see the shown rule changing that range.

(You are using the function's failure to work as one might think it would to actually be the accomplishing operator achieving your goal. It's sort of like wanting a pile of trash removed, convincing people that the stuff in the pile is valuable, looking away while they steal some, and eventually having no trash left in that. You are using failure to achieve a worthwhile goal.)